# How to fix bottom of text being cut off in IntelliJ 14.1?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, pycharm

Since I upgraded from IntelliJ 14 to 14.1, the bottom of my text for menus, etc. is being cut off.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Contrary to appearances, I am not editing DaqUtil or DaoUtil, but rather DagUtil.

How can I fix the file tree, tabs, and text boxes from not having the bottom cut off?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. It looks the default system font is Cantarell 11.

---

EDIT: I found and tried [tuxjdk](https://code.google.com/p/tuxjdk/). It fixes the problem, though the fonts appear at a different default size. That's not really an issue -- it's easier enough to adjust. The real deal breaker is that it makes IntelliJ **crawl** beyond all usability. :(

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have chosen the option `Override default fonts` in the intellij, the mentioned issue can be fixed by **`unCheck`** that override option in the below path,

```
Preferences -> Appearance and Behavior -> Appearance -> Override default fonts
```

[image]

If you need to customize the default font and to resolve the mentioned issue, try to change the font size.

Good luck.!

Comment: The mentioned option is unchecked. Also I checked it, and tested almost all of my fonts but I couldn't distinguish letter 'g' from 'q'. (At least in font size of 13 or more). unchecking it again didn't solve the issue. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am also having trouble with UI text being misaligned vertically, especially in UI text input boxes, such as seen in the OP's picture of the "rename" dialog. I am using Android Studio 2.1 (which is based on Intellij IDEA, not sure what version though). I am running it on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, which uses the GNOME 3.18 release.

I was able to improve the situation by using the options in the main **Settings...** dialog, under the **Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance** category. The one thing I've tried so far that works is to check the **Override default fonts by (not recommended)** checkbox, and to then play around with the font & font-size settings. It seems like Android Studio (i.e. IntelliJ) inherits the system font, which for my version of GNOME is Cantarell, and its default size has been set to 12. When I change to different fonts, some of them have similar problems where the bottom parts of text get cut off, but there are other fonts that work *much* more nicely! I set the font to Droid Sans (keeping the size at 12) and many of the UI widgets that previously had very bad alignment and cut-off issues now appear correctly, at least to my eyes. I don't claim that Droid Sans is a silver bullet solution for this, so if you try this fix, remember to try many different fonts, and perhaps even install some extra fonts from your package manager to test.

I know the program tells you that fiddling with these settings is "not recommended", but so far this solution has been a big improvement for me. Before I tried this fix, the Git plugin for AS/IDEA cut off the bottom half or more of the commit message, which was ridiculous. Now I can see all of it, which is wonderful.

Comment: Works great! I set mine to the Ubuntu font, size 14 (I'm running UbuntuGNOME 16.04)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed, at least as of Intellij 14.1.3. The spacing is further apart.

[image]

Comment: Not for me on Idea 14.1.3 (latest today) and Oracle JDK 1.8.0_31 :( Any help?